# How was Indrajeet as a person and are there any similarities between indrajeeta and Arjuna in their accomplishments?

Tags: arjuna, indrajit

Indrajeet, the son of Ravana , was considered to be the most prominent and dominant warrior of treta yuga, being the only person to get the entitlement of atimaharathi. So,the interest to know more about the childhood and training of this wonder warrior arose in my mind. Can anyone share the complete outline of his childhood days and his personality both as a child and an adult.

The other question that naturally arose is a bit of a comparative question , i.e who was better in terms of archery skills, power and achievements(exclude the nivatkavacha part)between the mighty Arjuna and Indrajit . Was Indrajeet also unconquerable like Arjuna before the last battle with Lakshmana ? Was his archery skills like that of Rama , Lakshmana and Arjuna ? Was his achievements as glorious a Arjuna ?